# Updating React useState alongside some global state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following:

```
const Foo = () => {
  let [callReqSuccess, setCallReqSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [addToNotifState] = useAddToNotifState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (callReqSuccess) {
      addToNotifState("success", "Meeting request sent successfully");
      setCallReqSuccess(false);
    }
  }, [callReqSuccess, addToNotifState]);

  const submitForm = async (data) => {
    // ... post data
    setCallReqSuccess(true);
    // here setQueryData sets the global state
    setQueryData(someData); 
  };
  // ... rest of code
};
```

Upon successful form submission, I expect the local `useState` to be set to true.

And in the subsequent `<Foo />` render, the local state `callReqSuccess` to be `true`.
However, that does not happen.

Which is because, (I suspect), the code `setQueryData(someData)` updates the global state & React discards the local `<Foo />` update?

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Would you be able to share the code where `setQueryData` is defined?

Comment: in your useEffect, whenever `callReqSuccess` turns true, you're immediately setting it to false again. this causes another render. maybe that's your issue? how are you checking that the local state is not `true` as expected?

Comment: @Aneesh its an external lib called React-Query (caches data). The logic is that upon form submission, the global cache is updated manually above in the code. To answer szaman, the state (useState) is not updated in the 1st instance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet shared, your assumption is correct.

The reason subsequent `Foo`s do not have the global property set is because the `Foo` component itself initializes with `false` for `callReqSuccess`

Every new `Foo` created will be set to `false` irrespective of the global value.

I would suggest, if possible, pass the global value as the initial value of `callReqSuccess` when initializing the state:

`const [callReqSuccess, setCallReqSuccess] = useState(yourGlobalValueVariable);`

Comment: Thank you Aneesh. Yes, I think I will have to create some mechanism (createContext maybe) to communicate updates. Keeping the question open for now in-case anyone has any further clarification to add.